# Integrate over piecewise function defined using /;

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

```
f[x_] := x /; x<0 
f[x_] := x^2 /; x>=0 
Integrate[f[x],{x,-1,1}]
```

The above does not work (Mathematica returns it unevaluated), but the 
below does.

```
g[x_] = Piecewise[{ {x,x<0}, {x^2,x>=0}}] 
Integrate[g[x],{x,-1,1}]
```

Why? More importantly, I've written a lot of code using the `/;` form: 
is there any way I can make it work and/or automagically convert it to 
Piecewise form without having to rewrite my code?

In real life, I'm doing something like
`Integrate[Cos[n x] f[x], {x, -1, 1}]`
for arbitrary n, and want a symbolic result, so NIntegrate won't solve my problem.

Comment: `NIntegrate[f[x], {x, -1, 1}]` will work and can be used with either `Rationalize` or `RootApproximant` to return `-1/6`.

Comment: @BobHanlon Unfortunately won't work if the integration contains variables other than x.

Comment: I would consider `/;` a programming construct, while `Piecewise` is meant for representing a mathematical concept.  `Piecewise` was designed with symbolic manipulation in mind.  `/;` is for controlling evaluation.  These are two entirely different uses, and many constructs have two versions in Mathematica for this reason.  Some others don't and the line between 'math' and 'programming' can be blurry (e.g. I'd also consider `If` a programming construct but it does work in `Integrate`) ... which can cause problems and confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference lies in the evaluation of `f` vs. `g`. Consider what happens when you supply them with a symbol, e.g.

```
f[x]
(* f[x] *)
```

versus

```
g[x]
(* Piecewise[{{x, x < 0}, {x^2, x >= 0}}, 0] *)
```

So, `Integrate` does not see the inside of `f[x]`, and, more importantly, it cannot do any symbolic evaluation on it because `Condition` (`/;`) prevents it from doing so.  A similar problem arises if you use `PatternTest`, instead, e.g.

```
h[x_?Negative] := x
h[x_?NonNegative] := x^2
Integrate[h[x], {x, -1, 1}]
(* Integrate[h[x], {x, -1, 1}] *)
```

Comment: OK, is there any "magic" way to convert one form to the other? (ie, a way that requires minimal effort on my part?)

Comment: @barrycarter I've been thinking about it. Provided that the conditions are simple, this works: `Piecewise[(DownValues[f][[All, 2]] /. Verbatim[Condition][a_, b_] :> {a, b})]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I added it as neither evaluate to `True`, so the rhs is never seen by `Integrate`. Similar problem, same result.